# understanding heapq push pop

Tags: python, heap

My goal was to sort a dictionary by values for the top ten. It seemed appropriate to use a heap. So i read up on pythons heapq and wrote this:

```
def top_ten_hash_tags(ranked_hash_tags):
    desc_hash_tags = []
    for hash_tag, rank in ranked_hash_tags.items():
        heapq.heappush(desc_hash_tags, (rank, hash_tag))
    top_ten = desc_hash_tags[0:10]
    while top_ten:
        i = heapq.heappop(top_ten)
        rank, hash_tag = i[0], i[1]
        print hash_tag.encode('utf-8'), (rank *-1.0)
```

It gave nearly the correct results, so close in fact that i didn't notice it was wrong.

After a bit i tested it against some borrowed code:

```
sorted_tags = sorted(ranked_hash_tags.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for i in sorted_tags[0:10]:
    print i[0].encode('utf-8'), i[1]
```

and noticed my mistake. So what went wrong with my original code?

Comment: You are popping from `top_ten` but never define it in the function. What is it's value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters good catch, i updated it. Now that i look at it, my hunch is that because i sliced off the top elements maybe the heap didn't... reheapfiy the entire set of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 10 entries in the heap do NOT always contain the 10 lowest keys. To get the 10 lowest, you have to pop from the (whole) heap 10 times.

(If the N first entries always contained the N lowest, what you would have is a sorted list, not a heap!)

In general, don't modify the list that represents your heap using anything but the heapq functions.